# Is solution to $\Gamma(x+1)=121$ algebraic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, gamma-function

If I had the following: $$x!=\Gamma(x+1)=121$$We see that $x\approx5$.

But is the exact value of $x$ algebraic?

For some non-whole number $x$ input that is algebraic, I think the output of the Gamma function is not algebraic, but I am unsure.

Because there does exist some $x$ that satisfies $\Gamma(x+1)=121$, where we see $121$, the output, as algebraic, but this does not tell me much about whether or not $x$ will be algebraic.

Comment: It's true $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ for example.  But you should really not use the notation $x!$ unless $x$ is a non-negative integer, just use $\Gamma(x+1)$ instead.

Comment: Also, look at the graph of $\Gamma$ and you'll see there are infinitely many $x$ that give you $121$.

Comment: A result which would be useful here would be of a sort "for every algebraic noninteger $\alpha$, $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is transcendental". Unfortunately, to my knowledge, pretty much nothing is known about values of $\Gamma$ for nonintegral arguments.